# Toolbar not responding to Listview scroll events

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an activity which contains a custom toolbar and a simple listview. I want the toolbar respond when the listview is scrolled. However, it is not working.

Here is the .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abdralabs.talksee.HistoryActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/history_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/history_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_history"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </ListView>
```

Here is the .java file

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.history_toolbar);
        /*
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        */
        toolbar.setTitle("History");
        String[] rcArray = {"A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"};



        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_history, rcArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_history);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        /*
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                break;
        }
        */
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT:**
**In response to rafsanahmad007's answer**
I have applied the changes as per your suggestion but still there is no change. 
When I scroll through the ListView there is no change to the size of the ToolBar. However, when I click on the ToolBar itself and make an up & down motion the ToolBar moves up & down too. What I want to achieve is, when I scroll the ListView downwards the ToolBar should collapse and when I scroll the ListView upwards the ToolBar should get to its normal size/position.

The following pictures depict how the ToolBar is responding currently.
[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the above pics, the ListView is not being scrolled, but the ToolBar itself is being scrolled. What I want is, when I scroll the ListView the ToolBar should scroll only during that time. I hope I have clarified myself.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

you can also get Help from [Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android-41aff9c5c468#.hbx43kd6n)

Comment: it should work ... see this:  [Link](https://android.jlelse.eu/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android-41aff9c5c468#.p2l5ugwue)  i am not sure what kind of scroll u want to achieve...

Comment: I have followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqTRbOp2odU&t=8s) for adding the toolbar to my activity. However, in the tutorial a NestedScrollView is used but here I have used a ListView. Could this be the reason it's not functioning properly?
Basically,I want the toolbar to maximize/minimize when I scroll through the ListView.

Comment: go through the link i provided.. and check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks you, I will go through the link. Also, I removed android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  from the AppBar but still no change.

Comment: I have tried as per the link you have provided but still there is no change.

Comment: I have added pics to depict how the UI is currently behaving, please check my edit. Thanks.